Failed to finish reCAPTCHA setup and now can't login to my site
All went well until I didn't read the welcome email and didn't click "Finish Setup" which told me to add the code my website that would make the image show up on the reCAPTCHA form to make it work. So I'm left with this:

I logged out of my WordPress website to test it and now I can't get back in to do anything.
Worse yet, WordPress won't allow me to reset my password to it or I could possibly get in to it that way. No reason, just "Password reset is not allowed for this user." I tried my PHP database but there isn't a WP database there so no password there.

How are you adding the reCAPTCHA? A plugin? Other code? You definitely have a database.

I added it within another plugin called Extended Development that did a search of my site after all of its installation and recommended the reCAPTCHA. I have a database of the site, but nothing with a WP pw.

If you have FTP access, just change the name of the plugin folder, e.g., add -bak to folder name. That will disable it. Then login, then remove the -bak from the folder. Now you can update the code for the reCAPTCHA. Where are you hosting this site?

I have managed to get back into the site. Now I just need to fix the reCAPTCHA by getting to the base html of the page. No idea how to do that within WordPress.

you can try looking into file header.php if you want to get to the base html of the page, for whatever reason.

You can get to that in WordPress? I have to get to it in order to add the reCAPTCHA code.

In your theme folder, look at footer.php Add the reCAPTCHA code to that file. I'm assuming it's JS script. Another way, is in functions.php in your theme - add add_action( 'wp_footer', static function() { ?> -- your JS here -- <?php }); This will output the code in the footer.

I have solved the problem by using a different kind of reCAPTCHA: Captcha Them All. It is a plugin that requires no coding and may be found within the WordPress Directory. You can download it here: Captcha Them All. I sincerely wish WP had made that option clear in the first place. Nevertheless, in case someone else asks, this was the best solution for me.
